# Group by query not generating the correct results each time

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I'm hoping for a bit of help with some SQL I've been struggling with for a while.  There are 2 examples below, one produces correct results and one doesn't.  I can see why but I just can't get my head around how to fix it.

The SQL I currently have is:

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ea.PersonId) Allocated, 
                CASE WHEN MAX(ea.EngagementAssignmentStatusId) = 2 THEN COUNT(DISTINCT ea.PersonId) ELSE 0 END Confirmed,
                ea.EngagementLevelID FROM EngagementAssignment ea 
    INNER JOIN EngagementLevel el ON ea.EngagementLevelId = el.EngagementLevelID
    WHERE el.JobId = 12906 AND 
    ea.EngagementLevelID = 105901 AND
    el.IsActive = 1 AND 
    ea.IsActive = 1 AND 
    ea.Isassigned = 1
    GROUP BY ea.EngagementLevelID
```

Project_Id 12906 data

```
lastname    firstname   PersonId    EngagementAssignmentStatusId
Person 1    Person 1    9233            2
Person 2    Person 2    9664            2
Person 3    Person 3    9508            2
Person 4    Person 4    7602            2
Person 5    Person 5    6216            2
Person 6    Person 6    6672            2
Person 7    Person 7    8798            2
Person 8    Person 8    9424            2
Person 9    Person 9    8862            2
Person 10   Person 10   9938            1
Person 11   Person 11   9754            1
Person 12   Person 12   9659            1
Person 13   Person 13   7441            2
Person 14   Person 14   8532            2
Person 15   Person 15   7106            2
```

Project_Id 6756 data

```
lastname    firstname   PersonId    EngagementAssignmentStatusId
Person 1    Person 1    5045            1
Person 1    Person 1    5045            1
Person 2    Person 2    4583            1
Person 2    Person 2    4583            1
Person 2    Person 2    4583            1
Person 2    Person 2    4583            1
Person 2    Person 2    4583            1
Person 2    Person 2    4583            1
Person 2    Person 2    4583            1
Person 2    Person 2    4583            1
Person 3    Person 3    4584            1
Person 3    Person 3    4584            1
Person 3    Person 3    4584            1
Person 3    Person 3    4584            1
Person 3    Person 3    4584            1
Person 4    Person 4    7192            1
Person 4    Person 4    7192            1
Person 4    Person 4    7192            1
Person 4    Person 4    7192            1
Person 4    Person 4    7192            1
Person 4    Person 4    7192            1
Person 4    Person 4    7192            1
Person 4    Person 4    7192            1
Person 4    Person 4    7192            1
Person 5    Person 5    6939            1
Person 5    Person 5    6939            1
Person 5    Person 5    6939            1
Person 6    Person 6    4802            1
Person 7    Person 7    5074            1
Person 7    Person 7    5074            1
Person 7    Person 7    5074            1
Person 7    Person 7    5074            1
Person 7    Person 7    5074            1
Person 7    Person 7    5074            1
```

What I am trying to get is the number of people that are

Allocated,
Confirmed (EngagementAssignmentStatusId=2) 
for an EngagementLevelId, hence the group by.

The 2 large data sets are the base data for the 2 projects.  The case when max() statement produces incorrect results for project 105901.

The result for Confirmed should be 12 because there are 12 out of the 15 total records that have EngagementAssignmentStatusId = 2.

Can someone please help.

Thank you

Comment: Can you please explain what are you trying to do here ? And what's wrong with your current query ? `one produces correct results and one doesn't` doesn't gives us much information on your requirement. Also the 2 large data set that you posted is the sample data ?  the current result of your query ? Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You are going to somehow post the sample data. Just enough to demonstrate the problem. I suggest you exclude columns and joins until you have just the part that isnt working and then post that. If you can reduce your data set down to 1 or two rows that demonstrate the problem then we can probably help. Although if you go through that process you will probably solve it yourself.

Comment: I suggest you zero in on _one_ problem, for example, in your first example, Confirmed should be 15, not 12. Can you recreate just a minimal reproducton of this issue? I know it's sometimes difficult to get the level of detail right but I feel there is more detail here than what anyone can chew through. Also you're going to need to align columns with data in your sample data and label each piece clearly.

Answer (score 1):

"Conditional aggregates" are formed by placing a case expression inside the aggregate function.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT ea.PersonId) Allocated
  , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ea.EngagementAssignmentStatusId = 2 THEN ea.PersonId END) Confirmed
  , ea.EngagementLevelID
FROM EngagementAssignment ea
INNER JOIN EngagementLevel el ON ea.EngagementLevelId = el.EngagementLevelID
WHERE el.JobId = 12906
AND ea.EngagementLevelID = 105901
AND el.IsActive = 1
AND ea.IsActive = 1
AND ea.Isassigned = 1
GROUP BY
    ea.EngagementLevelID
```

Comment: You were right TomC, I did the steps you suggested and yes I did solve the problem myself.  I should really have been able to work that out myself but I was getting in a bit of a tangle.  Thanks so much for everyone's help.